# How to allow cookies in Windows Server 2016 via scripting?

Tags: windows-server-2016

I am not able to use cookie at all for any external site on a Windows Server 2016.

[image]

However I need to connect to some external for some software activation.

Is it possible to change the security by way of scripting? I am using Terraform to provision these servers. Powershell script and any other other scripting language is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have IE's enhanced security configuration enabled. It is on by default on all Windows server systems, and it blocks an awful lot of things, making web browsing basically impossible.

You can disable it from Server Manager; here is a question on SO about how to script that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368305/disable-ie-security-on-windows-server-via-powershell.